# Cisco Archives,

Tags: cisco, router

wondering is it possible to archive running config to two destinations weekly (schedules archive)

means can we have two paths ?

I've tried to use two path commands which overwrites the old path command.

Regards,
Saad B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not natively with the `archive` command. However, there are things like kron that can run commands and scripts on a schedule. You could also setup an EEM to trigger similar to the way `archive` works (save the config on change.) And of course, you can have an external management system retrieve the configs as necessary. (search my previous answers for my snmp scripts)